How can I get this d3js custom shape?
enter image description here
I am trying to create the shape of the image using d3js (if it's any simpler way, please let me know)
I tried doing it but I don't get it right, I don't get the end and start position quite well, i tried adding numbers manually until it kinda looks good, and also i want to remove the gapangle, I think is useless:
enter image description here
This is the code that I used for getting the shape till now:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const width = 1000; // Canvas width
    const height = 1000; // Canvas height
    const innerOuterRadius = 280; // Outer radius of the inner segments
    const outerInnerRadius = 295; // Inner radius of the outer segments
    const segmentColor = "#265152"; // Color for the segments
    const lineColor = "#FF0000"; // Color for the connecting lines
    const gapAngle = 0.05; // Gap between segments (in radians)
    const inclinationAngle = 0.06; // Small inclination for connectors (in radians)

    // Segment sizes (in degrees)
    const innerSegmentSizes = [133, 133]; // Inner segments
    const outerSegmentSizes = [40, 40]; // Outer segments to fill gaps

    // Convert degrees to radians
    const innerSegmentSizesRadians = innerSegmentSizes.map((deg) => (deg * Math.PI) / 180);
    const outerSegmentSizesRadians = outerSegmentSizes.map((deg) => (deg * Math.PI) / 180);

    // Create the SVG canvas
    const svg = d3
        .select("#c4")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`);

    // Function to calculate polar coordinates
    const polarToCartesian = (radius, angle) => ({
        x: radius * Math.cos(angle),
        y: radius * Math.sin(angle),
    });

    // Draw inner segments (large, positioned symmetrically)
    innerSegmentSizesRadians.forEach((segmentAngle, index) => {
        const startAngle = index === 0 ? 0 : Math.PI; // Opposite sides
        const endAngle = startAngle + segmentAngle;

        const arc = d3
            .arc()
            .innerRadius(innerOuterRadius - 3)
            .outerRadius(innerOuterRadius)
            .startAngle(startAngle)
            .endAngle(endAngle);

        svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", segmentColor);
    });

    // Draw outer segments to fill spaces between inner segments
    outerSegmentSizesRadians.forEach((segmentAngle, index) => {
        const startAngle = index === 0
            ? innerSegmentSizesRadians[0] + gapAngle
            : innerSegmentSizesRadians[0] + Math.PI + gapAngle;
        const endAngle = startAngle + segmentAngle;

        const arc = d3
            .arc()
            .innerRadius(outerInnerRadius)
            .outerRadius(outerInnerRadius + 3)
            .startAngle(startAngle)
            .endAngle(endAngle);

        svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", segmentColor);
    });

    // Add connecting lines between the start and end of inner segments
    innerSegmentSizesRadians.forEach((segmentAngle, index) => {
        const startAngle = index === 0
            ? innerSegmentSizesRadians[0] + gapAngle + 1.517
            : innerSegmentSizesRadians[0] + Math.PI + 1.567; // Start of the inner segment
        
        const endAngle = startAngle + segmentAngle * 0.357; // End of the inner segment

        // Calculate the start and end points for the red lines
        const pointsToConnect = [
            { angle: startAngle }, // Start of the segment
            { angle: endAngle },   // End of the segment
        ];

        pointsToConnect.forEach(({ angle }) => {
            const innerPoint = polarToCartesian(innerOuterRadius, angle);

            // Shift the outer angle slightly to incline the connector
            const inclinedOuterAngle = angle + (index === 0 ? -inclinationAngle : inclinationAngle);
            const outerPoint = polarToCartesian(outerInnerRadius, inclinedOuterAngle);

            svg.append("line")
                .attr("x1", innerPoint.x)
                .attr("y1", innerPoint.y)
                .attr("x2", outerPoint.x)
                .attr("y2", outerPoint.y)
                .attr("stroke", lineColor)
                .attr("stroke-width", 2);
        });
    });
});



I just put this at the end where
const lineLengthExtension = 2.2, lineLengthReduction = 2.2;

pointsToConnect.forEach(({ angle }, pointIndex) => {
        const innerPoint = polarToCartesian(innerOuterRadius - lineLengthReduction, angle);
        const inclinedOuterAngle = angle + (pointIndex === 0 ? inclinationAngle : -inclinationAngle);
        const extendedOuterPoint = polarToCartesian(outerInnerRadius + lineLengthExtension, inclinedOuterAngle);

        svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1", innerPoint.x)
            .attr("y1", innerPoint.y)
            .attr("x2", extendedOuterPoint.x)
            .attr("y2", extendedOuterPoint.y)
            .attr("stroke", lineColor)
            .attr("stroke-width", 3);
    });


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
